# Death of persons by God

Tags: gods, atma, naraka, swarga

There are many stories about Hindu gods killing bad persons(Asuras). When they are killed, do the bad persons feel pain? Or do they just vanish from the universe? What will happen to them after getting killed by God? Will they go to hell or heaven or will their soul get destroyed?

Comment: soul never gets created nor destroyed. Many asuras killed by Vishnu get moksha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What will happen to them after getting killed by God, will they go to hell or heaven or soul itself gets destroyed?

In Hinduis  evey Danava ,Daitya  or Manushya got killed by Bhagvanta for some specific reason ,usually due to their past karmas. They were either realeased from their bondage or got moksha ,by getting being killed through God. Some of them were released by curse , some attained heaven ,some even merged with god himself immidieately.

Lets see this with some examples. -

Shishupal's soul merged with krishna when Shree Krishna killed Shishupala after his 101th sin  in Rajasuya Yajna of Yudhisthira.Shishupala was very much jealous of Pandavas and Krishna ,when he insulted krishna ,Krishna released his Sudarshana Chakra on him and killed him on the spot in front of all. While everyone was watching this incidence his soul in the form of flame merged with Shree-Krishna.  Shishupala was Obsessed with hatred of Krishna from last three births.

> तावदुत्थाय भगवान् स्वान् निवार्य स्वयं रुषा ।
>  शिरः क्षुरान्तचक्रेण
>   जहार पततो रिपोः ॥[**SB 10.74.43**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/74/43)  ॥
>
> tāvad utthāya bhagavān svān nivārya svayaṁ ruṣā 
> śiraḥ
>   kṣurānta-cakreṇa ahāra patato ripoḥ
>
> At that point the Supreme Lord stood up and checked His devotees. He
>   then angrily sent forth His razor-sharp disc and severed the head of
>   His enemy as he was attacking.
>
> ---
>
> चैद्यदेहोत्थितं ज्योतिः वासुदेवमुपाविशत् ।
>   पश्यतां सर्वभूतानां
>   उल्केव भुवि खाच्च्युता ॥ [**SB 10.74.45**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/74/45) ॥
>
> caidya-dehotthitaṁ jyotir vāsudevam upāviśat
>  paśyatāṁ
>   sarva-bhūtānām ulkeva bhuvi khāc cyutā
>
> An effulgent l**ight rose from Śiśupāla’s body and, as everyone
>   watched, entered Lord Kṛṣṇa** just like a meteor falling from the sky
>   to the earth.

This shows that even the person who is having extreme hatred towards god gets released ,through constantly thinking about god. Shishupala in extreme hatred constantly were thinking about lord so he merged with god at end.

---

Similarly Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakasshpu both were assistants of Lord. But due to a curse they were born as as Danavas. Lord killed them and released them from curse and called them back to his abode by eliminating their karmas by himself killng them.

> एतौ तौ पार्षदावस्य शापाद्यातावसद्गतिम् ।
>  पुनः कतिपयैः स्थानं
>   प्रपत्स्येते ह जन्मभिः ॥[**SB 3.19.29**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/19/29)॥
>
> etau tau pārṣadāv asya śāpād yātāv asad-gatim
>  punaḥ katipayaiḥ
>   sthānaṁ prapatsyete ha janmabhiḥ
>
> These two personal assistants of the Supreme Lord, having been cursed,
>   have been destined to take birth in demoniac families. After a few
>   such births, they will return to their own positions.

---

Hinduism scriptures especially Bhagwat Gita tells us that soul can't be destroyed by any means , so the souls those who  killed by god did not got destroyed ,soul is the purest thing it can not be destroyed.But those souls either got heaven either released or merged with god.

These are only coulple of examples but , in every such story in hinduism puranas we can observed such a case.

Comment: Nice explanation, What about their feelings will they feel pain when getting killed by God?

Comment: I believe It is a joy of sorts because.. they met "their  match". The opponents were equally balanced in stature even if directed in opposite ways.This awareness removes pain as the slain also feel "the right thing ultimately happened". Note that there is neither pleasure nor pain in true spirituality..  It is even shown symbolically in some  cinema (e.g., the Light of soul from the slain Ravana re-enters the Godhead, the most stable destination).